# EF4 STE Access to deleted entity

Tags: entity-framework-4, self-tracking-entities

How can I access deleted entity in self tracking entities graph?
I understand that in case I use MarkAsDeleted on the objects contained in a collection they are moved to ObjectsRemovedFromCollectionProperties of the parent entity, but how to access deleted objects that are not in a collection?

Thanks
Jakub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted reference is not directly exposed but you can debug `ApplyChanges` to see where it comes from. If you want to have the reference to deleted object you can simpy use return value from `MarkAsDeleted`.

Comment: I have finally found that deleted references are thrown into OrginalValues Property of the parent object.